# Force dismiss iOS share sheet manually Swift iOS 8 and 9

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity, ios-sharesheet

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to display options. Then select Twitter or Facebook, it appears **iOS share sheet**.

Is there any way to dismiss share sheet manually?
I cant see any delegate to this.

Here is my code:

```
let arrObjectsToShare = [self, finalTextToShare, secondActivityItem]

let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: arrObjectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [
                    UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,....etc]

activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: String?, bool: Bool, dictType: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print(activityType)
    }

self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Mention:**
When iOS share sheet is up to screen, keyboard is shown also.
I tried to dismiss keyboard, at least, But no way:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Really need help with this.
Thanks

**UPDATE1 - Screenshots added**
[image: This is <code>UIActivityViewController</code>]
[image: This is <code>iOS share sheet</code> or <code>com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter</code> or <code>plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post</code>]

Comment: It's a view controller. Dismiss it like any other view controller presented with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Comment: @maddy I am presenting UIActivityViewController with above method.   But this one is dismissed when iOS Share Sheet is up. I am not sure if is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `iOS Share Sheet`  is displayed, and call this method:
`self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` share sheet is dismissed successfully.

Comment: Please ask another question. This is not an answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @HatemAlimam I provided answer. It is working perfect. But I asked a new question.  Thanks

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski I will create a new question, and add link to this post. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the activity view controller with:

```
self.dismissViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.  Any idea how I can check if iOS share sheet is displayed on the screen?

Comment: @Bonnke you can use some flag in completion handler to know that it has been displayed.

Comment: @rshev That completion handler is called after user hits CANCEL or POST of iOS share sheet.  I need to invalidate that manually.

Comment: @Bonnke I meant `completion` within `presentViewController`.

Comment: @rshev I am not sure if you get my question. `completion` within `presentViewController` is called after `UIActivityViewController` was displayed.  I need to force dimiss `com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter`  iOS Share Sheet

Comment: @Bonnke finally got your question. Thought about `UIActivityViewController`.